# Facebook debug not clearing cache

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, caching, share

I recently launched a new version of a site I'm in charge of. The new version uses a different CMS and is a entirely different codebase. Now when I try to share a page from this site, I'm getting the data from the old site in the sharing preview window (facebook). I have set the correct meta og tags, and in the Facebook debug tool I tried fetching the new information but to no avail.

I also tried the following which was suggested to me:

```
http://www.example.com?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHIN
```

I simply can't get it to fetch the new information. When checking the scraped URL, I can see the source code of the old site that hasn't been online in over a month.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you re-scrape the URL in debug tool? Does it shows any errors? Do you have an example URL for us?

Comment: Yes I did, it still shows the old site. There are warnings but no errors, these are related to the old site though as that is still the only thing it sees.

The site is bredband2.com

Comment: Did you change DNS settings for the domain recently? (Tried to use the W3C HTML validator on your site, and got an error message that the hostname could not be resolved the first time.) In that case, it simply might take a while for Facebook to get new DNS information.

Comment: Yes I did, three or for weeks ago. Still, should that not be enough time?

Comment: This is not enough information, I would post the actual URL you're scraping so people can test what you mention. Is it still an issue?

Comment: The problem was solved. It was a DNS issue having something to do with Facebook using IPV6. Our tech department solved it so I'm unable to give exact information on what the problem consisted of or how it was solved, unfortunately.